# A question about a proof in a paper on complete multipartite graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, graph-theory

I was recently reading the following article/paper:

"Proof of a conjecture on distance energy change of complete multipartite graph due to edge deletion"

by Shaowei Sun and Kinkar Chandra Das.

[Paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379520305127?via%3Dihub#!) and DOI: 10.1016/j.laa.2020.10.029.

I am facing difficulty in understanding a proof. I am attaching a screenshot of the part:

[image]

**I have the following question: How do the four equations in $\lambda$ give us the function $f(x)$?**

---

Also please let me know if I am allowed to ask such questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four equations for $y_1,y_2,y_3,y_n$ have a nonzero solution if $\lambda$ is such that the determinant of the coefficient matrix vanishes.
The coeffient matrix (with $\lambda\mapsto x$) is
$$M=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -x & 2 & 2 (p-1) & q-1 \\
 2 & -x & p-1 & 2 (q-1) \\
 2 & 1 & 2 (p-2)-x & q-1 \\
 1 & 2 & p-1 & 2 (q-2)-x \\
\end{array}
\right).$$
I checked that $\det M=0$ is identical to $f(x)=0$ with $f(x)$ given by equation 1 and $n=p+q$. (The post does not specify $n$, but I presume this is the relation.)